# C++ Removing empty elements from array

Tags: c++, arrays

I only want to add a[i] into the result array if the condition is met, but this method causes empty elements in the array as it adds to result[i]. Is there a better way to do this?

```
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    if(a[i]>=lower && a[i]<=upper)
    {
        count++;
        result[i]=a[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, write it to `result[count]` before `count++;`.

Comment: Please make a [mre]. It's unclear what you mean by "add a[i]".and what `count` is supposed to be used for.

Comment: Use [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) with a suitable [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead.

Answer (score 4):

you can let `result` stay empty at first, and only `push_back` `a[i]` when the condition is met:

```
std::vector<...> result;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if (a[i] >= lower && a[i] <= upper)
    {
        result.push_back(a[i]);
    }
}
```

and `count` you can leave out, as `result.size()` will tell you how many elements satisfied the condition.

---

to get a more modern solution, like how Some programmer dude suggested, you can use [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) in combination with [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) to achieve the same thing:

```
std::vector<...> result;

std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(result),
    [&](auto n) {
        return n >= lower && n <= upper;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in c++ are dumb.

They are just pointers to the beginning of the array and don't know their length.

If you just arr[i] you have to be sure that you aren't out of bounds. In that case it is undefined behavior as you dont know what part of meory have you written over. You could as well write over a different variable or beginning of another array.

So when you try to add results to an array you already have to have the array created with enough space.

This boilerplate of deleting and creating dumb arrays so that you can grow the array is very efficiently done in `std::vector` container which remembers number of elements stored, number of elements that could be stored and the array itself. Every time you try to add element when the reserved space is full it creates a new array two times the size of the original one and copy the data over. Which is O(n) in worst case but O(1) in avarege case (it may deviate when the n is under certain threshold)

Then the answer from Stack Danny applies.

Also use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back` if you can it is able to construct the data type in place based on the constructor parameters and in other cases it tries to act like `push_back`. It basically does what you want the fastest way possible so you avoid as much copies as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
count=0;
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
   if(a[i]>=lower && a[i]<=upper)
   {
       count++;
       result[count] = a[i];
   }
}
```

Try this.

Your code was copying elements from a[i] and pasting it in result[i] at random places.
For example, if a[0] and a[2] meet the required condition, but a[1] doesn't, then your code will do the following:

```
result[0] = a[0]; 
result[2] = a[2];
```

Notice how result[1] remains empty because a[1] didn't meet the required condition. To avoid empty positions in the result array, use another variable for copying instead of i.